# Manually upload files to azure blob storage

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

Pretty new to Azure... I have see a blob in the Azure Management Portal, and also I have a vidéo to upload.

I just want to upload that **only one video to that concrete blob, nothing more**.

How can I do it? I see "Download", "Edit", "Delete", I can even create a new blob storage...

BUT **WHERE IS** THE BUTTON "**ADD A FILE** TO THAT BLOB"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Azure Tools for Visual Studio, you can upload files to your storage account.
[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683677.aspx#BK_ViewResources)

Comment: After installing the Azure SDK you can go to "View" "Cloud Explorer" in Visual Studio. From there you can select your container and open the Blob Container Editor which allows you to upload files.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot add a blob directly to a container from azure portal. What you need is some kind of a tool either you write one or download one. 
I would recommend [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) just because I have used it and it does the job, but alternatives are available.

You just need your storage account name and one of the access keys.

You can find the storage account name from Storages section of azure. 
For the access key you need to go into the storage account and click "Manage Access Keys".

Comment: Suggested tool is [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) - this link points to the new MS page to download it

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different storage explorers that enable you to browse and edit files within Storage - see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/03/11/windows-azure-storage-explorers-2014.aspx) for a full list. For command line file management you can use AzCopy, PowerShell or XPlat tools - all of which have documentation available [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/).

Answer (score 0):

Suggested Azure tool for such file operations is [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) , it has a user friendly GUI, and login is easy with Azure username & password credentials.